# OpenGL ES. Texture mapping on a given path

Tags: opengl-es, path, texture-mapping

Need to apply a texture on a given path.
The path is a set of points.

Tell me how to do or where to read about how to do it on Opengl ES?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider you have enough points for the shape to look good enough, otherwise you should do some interpolation get more of them..

I suggest you create a 2D vertex array from the points (an array of rectangles if you wish). At each point you need 2 vertices (v1, v2):

```
vector position = currentPoint;
vector way = nextPoint - currentPoint;
vector normal = normalized(way.y, -way.x);

v1 = position + normal*(ropeWidth*.5);
v1 = position - normal*(ropeWidth*.5);
```

You will probably put this in a `for` loop where you also need to set texture coordinates where X is always set to 1.0 and -1.0, Y goes for iterator `i` as `i/pointCount` (`i` needs to be floating though)

At this point you may just bind the texture and draw a triangle strip.